# Copy to samba share leave

Tags: 18.04, samba, shared-folders, copy

I have a samba share directly mounted from Nemo below

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:domain=domain,server=myserverurl,share=share,user=user/
```

And I'm trying to copy files to the server.

I can modify files on it, but copying just creates an empty file with a note

Error while copying **"document.pdf"**
Invalid argument

Comment: Is the name of the file being copied really document.pdf or does it have "funny" characters in it - like a colon? For example if I try to copy document:page1.pdf I will get either the "Invalid argument" error or a "no such file or directory" error.

Comment: No, there are no stranger characters. I tried it with various files, none work. txt, pdf... strangely enough, I can create files, and copy-paste into them. A python script on the server also could generate files on it no problem.